# Query reference array in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following class (pseudocode):

```
class External
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :data, type: Hash, default: {}, strip_email_addresses: true  
end

class Video
  embed_many :externals
```

and I want to query all videos that have a reference to an external which has a certain value in `data.Tags`. To make things harder, `Tags` is a comma-separated string, so I want to check if the text includes `value`, not if it's equal (although I could change this by making `Tags` into an array)

Comment: To make this really hard, you didn't give any example in your question of what the data looks like and you are asking people to guess. Whilst I like a good challenge I prefer to work without a blindfold. For myself as well as others, it's probably best if you present as much information to others as you have yourself if you really want help with a solution.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I'll update the question a bit